# Node-Webkit audio using local file

Tags: javascript, local, node-webkit

So i was trying to attach embed tag to the page with the following address:
file:///C:/Users/avihay/Downloads/Imagine Dragons - Radioactive.mp3
(even with backslahes as well)
but couldn't operate the situation.
for some reason the file cant be played when coming from local address (even when its allowed on node-webkit)
does anyone knows the perfect solution to this situation? :)

Comment: Have you tried a relative url? It worked for me while displaying PDFs

Comment: kind of a problem, cause the file loading should be dynamic

Comment: Meaning you want to load files outside the app's dir? That might be an issue...

Comment: it loads pictures that way :)

Comment: Try a relative url, if it works then as a dirty workaround you could copy the needed files to your working dir as temporary files and clean-up on exit :)

Comment: i get the file paths using file dialog, how am i supposed to open them a relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node-webkit doesn't support mp3 by default, but you can workaround that limitation by using custom built, platform-specific versions of libffmpeg as described [here](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Support-mp3-and-h264-in-video-and-audio-tag).

Comment: the link is broken now!

Comment: correct link: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Using-MP3-&-MP4-(H.264)-using-the--video--&--audio--tags.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because .mp3 audio is not supported for node-webkit. Use .ogg instead.